# Angular azure-service-bus

Tags: angular, azure-servicebus-queues

I creating an Angualar4 application and I am going to connect to an azure service bus.
I've installed the azure-arm-sb package(https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-arm-sb).

The first question is what package to use, there exist:

- azure-arm-sb
- azure-asm-sb
- azure-sb

The example on how to use says(for the azure-arm-sb) to add:

var msRestAzure = require('ms-rest-azure');
var ServicebusManagement = require('azure-arm-sb');

But this just give me this warning:

- app.component.ts (27,23): Cannot find name 'require'.

As fra as I understand it's better/correct to use import, but I haven't manage to import anyting from the azure-arm-sb.

Installing the the azure-sb however i manage to import i.e:

import { ServiceBusServiceClient } from 'azure-sb';

But I'm not sure how to use this and trying the command:

- import { ServiceBusServiceClient } from 'azure-sb';

gives this runtime error:

- ERROR TypeError: **WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2_azure_sb**.ServiceBusServiceClient is not a constructor

Does anybody know how to use the azure service buss package from an Angular application?

Comment: I think the azure npm packages are meant to be used on server side in a node.js backend.